# Rails turbo frame response not firing turbo:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails, turbo-frames

I have a standard inline edit using [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwire.dev/handbook/frames), that replaces the turbo frame of the `show` view with the turbo frame in the `_form`. But the `$(document).on "turbo:load", ->` event is not firing  in this case.

I don't see [another event](https://turbo.hotwire.dev/reference/events) that should be used. Any ideas how to run js on a response that replaces a turbo frame? (eg to initialise the datepicker in a form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event that fires when a frame loads is still under construction: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/59

The only events we currently have are `turbo:before-fetch-request` and `turbo:before-fetch-response`, that fire at the `document` level every time Turbo changes a frame or navigates pages. The content of the frame won't be loaded by the time the event fires, but it will allow you to potentially use the `loaded` property of the frame to hook up a promise that runs when the frame has loaded.

```coffee
$(document).on("turbo:before-fetch-response", (e) ->
  frame = document.getElementById("myFrame")
  # Frame has finished loading
  if frame.complete
    #run my code
  else
    # Frame is still loading, run this code when it finishes
    frame.loaded.then () ->
      # run my code
```

Otherwise you can write a Stimulus controller that wraps your datepicker initialisation, so that you don't have to watch for it coming in and out of the DOM.

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm more concerned that someone still writes coffeescript in 2021...

Comment: I wrote coffeescript as that appeared to be what the question was written in...

Comment: Fair enough!  :)

Comment: The coffeescript in the question wasn't written in 2021 if that eases your concerns @Askdesigners!