# Rails Turbo doesn't trigger turbo:load event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo, turbo-rails, hotwire

The turbo:load event is not fired after a turbo visit (as the [documentation](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events) says it should). It works as expected after the initial full-page load. I can catch the "turbo:before-fetch-response" event, but I have no luck with turbo:load, :render, :frame-render, :frame-load.

My turbo_stream request is format TURBO_STREAM to destroy an attachment. The controller response is

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream do
    render 'attachments/delete_document',
               locals: { target: "docs-list-#{img.id}" }
  end
end
```

and I'm returning two turbo-streams whose update and remove actions work as intended:

```
<turbo-stream action="remove" target="<%= target %>">
  <template></template>
</turbo-stream>

<turbo-stream action="update" target="flash_messages">
<template>
  <%= render partial: 'layouts/flash', formats: :html,
             locals: { type: :notice,
                       message: 'Attachment removed.' } %>
</template>
</turbo-stream>
```

(Note: This is a bump of another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857837/rails-turbo-frame-response-not-firing-turboload/71041653#71041653). The solution proposed there doesn't work in my case as the complete attribute only exists for [HTML img elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete).)
(I'm using @hotwired/turbo@^7.1.0, @hotwired/turbo-rails@^7.1.1 in Rails 7.0.1)

Answer (score 6):

I had resolve that problem with `turbo:render` event:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startFrontController)
document.addEventListener('turbo:render', startFrontController)

function startFrontController(event) {
  document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startFrontController)
  new FrontController().start()
}
```

See Turbo events documentation: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Sergio's answer, I ended up using one of the turbo-provided events - turbo:before-fetch-response in my case, since most other events didn't fire. Still not sure why.

However:
I found that the best answer is to use Stimulus. Provides a clean interface for adding javascript functionality.

Comment: Stimulus is the safest. And its performant.